# How do I average a signal over time using RMS in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have created a function to get the average of an incoming signal over time. The end goal is to get a singular average number from a microphone signal every five minutes, but I have put two seconds in the setInterval part to speed up the testing process. I've tried out some code using RMS equations, but I cannot seem to figure out what is going wrong.

The absoluteLevel is the incoming linear level between 0 and 1, which is being produced in a function above. The absoluteLevel variable is global. The sample rate is set to 44100.

Thanks in advance.

```
function measureLevel() {

    rmsTotal = Math.pow(absoluteLevel, 2) / sampleRate;
    counter++;

    if (counter === sampleRate) {
        rmsAverage = rmsTotal / counter;
        counter = 0;
        rmsTotal = 0;
    }

    console.log(rmsTotal);

}
window.setInterval(measureLevel, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assume that all of your variables were initialized already, and available like absoluteLevel. From what I can see there could be two problems:

1. rmsTotal was getting reset each time instead of accumulating.

   - I changed the name to 'meanSquare'
2. You need the square root of that mean square (average of squares)

   - I renamed rmsAverage to 'rootMeanSquare'

So I would suggest:

```
function measureLevel() {
    meanSquare += Math.pow(absoluteLevel, 2) / sampleRate;
    counter++;

    if (counter === sampleRate) {
        rootMeanSquare = Math.pow(meanSquare, 0.5);
        console.log('Counter reached. RMS: ' + rootMeanSquare);
        counter = 0;
        meanSquare = 0;
    }

    console.log(meanSquare);

}
window.setInterval(measureLevel, 2000);
```

I do have a worry though for you. If you run this function once every 2 seconds, and need 44100 samples for a rms, then you'll need 88200 seconds before you get your RMS output!!

If you can get your absoluteLevel very quickly, you might get a faster test with a loop:

```
function measureLevel() {
    counter = 0;
    meanSquare = 0;
    while counter < sampleRate {
        //RUN A SET ABSOLUTE LEVEL FUNC
        meanSquare += Math.pow(absoluteLevel, 2) / sampleRate;
        counter++;

        console.log(meanSquare);
    }
    rootMeanSquare = Math.pow(meanSquare, 0.5);
    console.log('Counter reached. RMS: ' + rootMeanSquare);
}
window.setInterval(measureLevel, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks BenD, this is really helpful. I've tried changing the sample rate but my browser crashes when I run the function. Is there a way to stop it draining my CPU? Cheers

Comment: Hmm, it is hard to tell without knowing how you are receiving absoluteLevel. However, if you are trying out the second segment of code, you could set the interval much greater or just run the function once since each call should loop until you get a reading.